# Wordpress Woocommerce functions working in local but not working in live

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I Tried to show the cart total quantity and total amount in cart dropdown.

But All the functions are working good in local but not working in the live AWS instance.

I have tried some methods like below which are working in local but not in live

```
WC()->cart->cart_contents_count
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()
WC()->cart->get_total()
WC()->cart->get_cart_total()
WC()->cart->cart_contents_total
WC()->cart->total
```

All working in local but not in live

The below  code I have tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
function header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <a class="cart-customlocation" id="from-function" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">
        <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->cart_contents_count), WC()->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - 
        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_total(); ?>
    </a>
    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

And also tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'header_add_to_cart_fragment' );
function header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <a class="cart-customlocation" id="from-function" href="<?php echo esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>">
        <?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - 
        <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
    </a>
    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-customlocation'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

Update:
As like the attached image quantity and total price is 0 but in local its ok.

[image: cart screenshot]

Comment: Please describe more what "not working" means in your case. What is the expected output? What is shown instead? Was there any warning or error messages?

Comment: @KoalaYeung the function  header_add_to_cart_fragment is not working as expected. Added a screenshot you can see  WC()->cart->cart_contents_count function returns 0 and also  WC()->cart->get_total() return 0 in the cart section.

Comment: It seems to be a problem of server cache configuration that stop some WooCommerce Ajax functionalities, so not really the right place to ask this question, may be ask it in [Server Fault *Stack Exchange site*.](https://serverfault.com/)